# Margin property not working but position property is. Why?

Tags: html, css, css-position, margins

I want to rewrite the html and css for this portion of a webpage.

First I tried using margins to push down the `#Header` div but it did not happen from the top: the header remain attached to the top border of the `#Container`.

```css
#Container {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 440px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#Header {
  background: #CF1111;
  width: 400px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Header"></div>
</div>
```

Then, my solution was using the `top` property with relative positioning

```css
#Container {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 440px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#Header {
  background: #CF1111;
  width: 400px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Header"></div>
</div>
```

Why didn't the `margin-top` work?

Comment: Screenshot is not attached.

Comment: It should work just fine.  It works fine here with margin-top: https://jsfiddle.net/ggs04qz9/

Comment: I just realized I added borders.  It didn't work without them.  As I just learned by the link to the duplicate question, without borders on your divs, you're seeing an effect called `margin-collapsing.`